# Erro no ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

Alguém sabe porque está dando este problema ?
Depois que alterei o nome do GoogleApiCliente ele dá este error =/

[image: Erro AdapterView]

```
 private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    adapterClientes = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, client);
    listView.setAdapter(adapterClientes);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            Object o = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Por favor, evite de colocar erros em capturas de tela, pois impossibilita que outras pessoas com o mesmo problema encontrem essa pergunta, além de impedir que usuários de leitores de tela tirem proveito do conteúdo.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida por isso que coloquei o código abaixo.

Comment: Mas não colocou a mensagem que te fez criar a pergunta. Quem buscar por ela não encontra do jeito que está.

Comment: Blz cara. Da próxima eu copio o erro e coloco na mão aqui. Obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O construtor do *ArrayAdapter* espera que lhe seja passado um objecto do tipo `ArrayList<>` mas você está a passar um objecto do tipo `GoogleApiClient`.

Altere

```
adapterClientes = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, client);
```

para

```
adapterClientes = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, clientes);
```